# Benefits of Homebrew Cask over tradicional installation method?

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I know how does Cask works and all the benefits I can get when using it in a brand new system, but what I want to know and I don't seem to find and answer anywhere is... would it be a good idea if I delete my previous installed software and replace them with cask versions? would I see some kind of improvement, or would it be a waste of time?

Comment: Do you see having a command line interface for installing and uninstalling software as an improvement?

Comment: Indeed I do, at least in case I need to reinstall all my apps I can do it with one command line... but my question is in my already configured system, would it be any difference between a traditional software installation and a Cask installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real advantage to reinstalling existing binaries using homebrew-cask. It's strictly a workflow improvement for when you need to install various softwares. For instance, if you wanted to have a script to install all your regularly used binaries on a new computer, that would be more efficient than manually visiting several sites and downloading, installing, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought that was the case and I tried first-hand yesterday after I installed Sierra and then just exec a .brew file with all the brew and cask packages.

Pd: do you know if new versions of this apps [i.e. Google Chrome] get updated by using `brew upgrade` command?

Answer (score -1):

Traditional software installation on some apps have automatic updates and some require the user to visit the apps website to do an update. Once the update is downloaded the user is required to click next, next, agree etc whilst it is satisfactory to do this for a few apps it can be time consuming.

One of the advantages of HBC is that it does an install without user interaction or sometimes a prompt for admin password. So if you do a reinstall of the OS you can use HBC to reinstall the additional apps.

At present there is no provision for updates using HBC so i have written scripts that take of some issues.

The scripts will create a file that lists the files to be updated including apps that are defined as latest. You can then modify the file to suit your requirements and install updates using my olinst script.

For more information visit my github.

https://github.com/pacav69/homebrew-homebrew-caskroom-offline-installer